# How can i remove certain Char of string in a azure logic app using wild a wild card

Tags: azure, replace, azure-logic-apps

I have a string in a variable in a logic app which looks like this `123,456,"A,B,C",789`

I want to replace the commas in "A,B,C" portion of the string so I end up with a new value of 123,456,"A B C",789.

I have tried a number of different things:

```
replace(variables('replaceval'),'*","*','')
replace(variables('replaceval'),'%","%','')
replace(variables('replaceval'),'","','')
```

but nothing seems to work is there a way to use wild card as the "A,B,C" could be "D,E,F"

Comment: Yes correct @Ibrar We need a Compose action to work with the string variable. And this Compose action will contain the replace function. And we need replace function to fix the issue in the given string. 
 
 So in the Compose action, @LJHHouston, you need to set the Input field to the following expression as given below, as this expression will be removing the quoted part of the string:
 
 `{  "replacedString": replace(variables('replaceval'), ',"', ' "')  }`

Comment: I do not want to remove the "A,B,C" Just the " ," to end up with "A B C". my final output should be 123,456,"A B C",789

Comment: yes @LJH the expression that I have shared, is working as expected. Check once.

Comment: sorry, I am having problems some what new to AZRUE. inputs": "@replace(variables('replaceval'), ',\"', ' \"')" I am getting this as my output from my compose.   123,456 "A,B,C",789

Comment: Ok
Try with this : 

**  "value": "@replace(replace(variables('replaceval'), ',\"', '\"'), ',', ' ')" ** 
 
Here as you can see The first replace() removes spaces after a comma within double quotes. It replaces `',"'` with `'\"'` and the second `replace()` replaces all other commas with spaces.

Hope this works for you and then this will give you the desired output as 
`123,456,"A B C",789`

Comment: OK sort of worked (123 456"A B C" 789) but it removed all the comma's. LOL actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@replace(replace(variables('replaceval'), ',\"', '\"'), ',', ' ')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I have reproduced in my environment with Compose actions and below are the expected results:

**`Design:`**

```
replace(replace(replace(outputs('Compose'),split(replace(outputs('Compose'),'"','{'), '{')[1],''),'"',''),',,',',')
```

[image]

**`Outputs:`**

[image]

If you want to replace or know what it is in the quotations use below design :

```
split(replace(outputs('Compose'),'"','{'), '{')[1]
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

If you want to replace anything you can use the output of compose 3 and use it replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "split" and "join" functions in combination with a loop to achieve this. Here's how you can do it step by step:

1. Initialize a variable to store the modified string: Create a
   variable, let's call it "MyModifiedString," and initialize it to an
   empty string.
2. Split the input string using a comma as the delimiter: Use the
   "split" function to split the input string into an array:

```
split(variables('InputString'), ',')
```

3. Iterate through the Substrings:Use a "For each" loop to iterate through the array of substrings.Replace Commas within Quoted Substrings:
   Inside the loop, use a "Compose" action to conditionally replace the commas within substrings enclosed in double quotes with spaces.

```
    If(
        startsWith(item(), '"'),
        replace(item(), ',', ' '),
        item()
    )
```

4. Join the modified substrings back together using commas as the delimiter:
   After the loop, use the "join" function to join the modified substrings back together using commas as the delimiter:

```
    join(outputs('For_each'), ',')
```

This method will replace the commas within the double-quoted portion of the string with spaces and store the modified string in the "ModifiedString" variable.

Answer (score -1):

In an Azure Logic App, you can use the" Compose" action in combination with a combination of Azure Functions and expressions to remove certain characters from a string using a wildcard. if you want, I will provide you a general step-by-step guide on achieving this.